Angular 18 Directive - Change color of button on hover
I'm learning how to create a simple custom directive using Angular 18 that can change the background color of an element. I'm referring to the code provided in the Angular documentation here but it doesn't work.
Is there anything I need to add to the code to make it work?
Custom Directive:
import { Directive,ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]',
  standalone: true
})
export class HighlightDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private render : Renderer2) {
   }

   @HostListener('mouseenter') OnMouseOver(eventData: Event){
      this.changeColor('yellow')
   }

   private changeColor(color :string)
   {
    this.render.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement,'backgroundcolor',color)
   }
}

Component :
<div  class="parent">
<p appHighlight >Product Component</p>
</div>

I have tried to get solution using HostBinding but its not working.
Expected: To understand how it works and what is the wrong in above code.

Why you change the background color in the method changeColor() with this.render.setStyle(…)? And why not with this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;?

@SwissCodeMen Renderer was meant to perform such operation in angular. If something can be done using angular shouldn't it be done that way?

please provide stackblitz for this and did you check that your directive is called or not? did you import directive correctly

In the component that is using the directive have you added the directive to imports like this
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 standalone: true,
 imports: [HighlightDirective],
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent {

also change
this.render.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement,'backgroundcolor',color)

to
this.render.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'background-color', color);

or
this.render.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', color);

it's kebab or camel case

Nice solution but still creating directive for such simple task is not preferred. We can use css

@MeetBhalodi I know that we can do it with just css styles but the question was about learning angular and why that directive didn't work so I provide suitable answer.

@Raziel, thank you for your solution. I realized that I had missed importing the directive in the component, and I also updated "backgroundcolor" to "background-color". After making these changes, everything is now working as expected.

This is a pure CSS style answer, you can use CSS variables to set the hover color dynamically using ngStyle.
global-styles.scss
:root {
  --hover-color: yellow; /* initial value */
}

.hover-me:hover {
  background-color: var(--hover-color);
}

main.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div  class="parent">
      <p [ngStyle]="{'--hover-color': 'red'}" class="hover-me">Product Component</p>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

